# Get a word's individuality!

Tags: code-golf, string, subsequence

I love `/usr/share/dict/words`; it's so handy! I use it for all my programs, whenever I can! You're going to take advantage of this ever so useful file to use, by testing a word's individuality.

---

**Input**

- A word; defined in this challenge as any string of characters
- `/usr/share/dict/words` in some format; you may hard code it, read from disk, assume it as a second argument, whatever makes the most sense in your challenge

**Output**

- A words individuality (see below)

A word's individuality is derived from the following equation:

```
<the number of words for which it is a substring> / <length of the word>
```

Let's take a look at an example:
`hello`. There are 12 words which have the substring `hello` in them, divided by `5` (hello's length), and hello's individuality is `12/5` or `2.4`

---

P.S. This is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf), so the lower the individuality score, the more individual

Because individuality is a long word, your program must be as short as possible

Good Luck!

---

**Test Cases**

You can use this convenient Node.js script, which fits the challenge requirements to fit your code. It is also how I generated the test cases:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var word = process.argv[2];

process.stdout.write("Reading file...")
fs.readFile("/usr/share/dict/words", function(err, contents) {
  console.log("Done")
  if (err) throw err;

  words = contents.toString().split("\n");

  var substrings = words.filter(w => w.indexOf(word) > -1).length;
  var length     = word.length;

  console.log(`${word} => ${substrings} / ${length} = ${substrings / length}`)
})
```

Test Cases:

```
hello => 12 / 5 = 2.4
individuality => 1 / 13 = 0.07692307692307693
redic => 52 / 5 = 10.4
ulous => 200 / 5 = 40
challen => 15 / 7 = 2.142857142857143
ges => 293 / 3 = 97.66666666666667
hidden => 9 / 6 = 1.5
words => 12 / 5 = 2.4
aside => 8 / 5 = 1.6
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around?  To make it more individual, have a higher individuality score?

Comment: Probably, but making breaking changes to the challenge when people may have started golfing would be unwise

Comment: Can we use other word lists instead? I think [this one](http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt) is easier to use (being a Windows user). The list is apparently not as long, so the individuality will be higher, but this doesn't alter the challenge the way I see it.

Comment: Is a word a substring of itself?

Comment: I assume a case-insensitive match ?

Comment: In order to keep answers uniform, I request you use the same word list, but keep in mind that you can accept it in any way. Getting the word list is not part of the challenge

Comment: @Flp.Tkc Yes, basically anything that can be grepped

Comment: @zeppelin in most wordlists, all the entries are lowercase. Additionally you can assume that all input will be lowercase

Comment: @MayorMonty
Ok, great, I've asked as the _/dict/words_ is not lowercase (at least not in my system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
#vy²å}ON/
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Z5wrLDpX1PTi8&input=YWJhIGFiYmEgYWJhYmEgYWJhYmFiYWJhIGFiYiBhYmJiIGFiYWJhIGxvbAphYmE)

```
#         Separate by newlines or spaces.
 vy       For each entry in the dictionary.
   ²å     1 if the second argument is a substring of the current word, 0 o.w.
     }    End loop.
      O   Sum ones and zeros.
       N  Get list size. 
        / Divide.
```

Comment: Looks like yours is going to be the shortest, but I'll give it a week or two

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <del>41</del>, <del>39</del>, <del>34</del>, <del>33</del>, 26 bytes

EDIT:

- Converted from function to a script
- One byte off by removing the *ignore case* flag
- Replaced *wc -l* with *grep -c*, saving 5 bytes. Thanks @Riley !

A rather trivial solution in *bash* + *coreutils*

**Golfed**

```
bc -l<<<`grep -c $1`/${#1}
```

**Test**

```
>cat /usr/share/dict/words| ./test ulous
7.60000000000000000000

>grep -i ulous /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l
38
```

Comment: Would `grep -ic $1` work instead of `grep -i $1|wc -l`?

Comment: True ! (always thought this to be a GNU extension, but it turns out to be a POSIX option indeed). Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>52</s> 49 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Kade, for assuming `w` to be the word list as list:

```python
f=lambda s,w:w>[]and(s in w[0])/len(s)+f(s,w[1:])
```

Previous solution:

```python
lambda s,w:sum(s in x for x in w.split('\n'))/len(s)
```

Assumes `w` to be the word list. I choose Python 3 because in my word list there are some Non-ASCII chars and Python 2 does not like them.

Comment: Since you are allowed to take the wordlist in any reasonable format, couldn't this work for 50 bytes: `f=lambda s,w:w>[]and (s in w[0])/len(s)+f(s,w[1:])`

Comment: I should note you can remove the space between `and` and `(` to make it 49 bytes.

Comment: @Kade awesome! Nice abuse of the lax requirements.

Comment: @Dopapp No, because this would not substring

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>45 36 33</s>  32 bytes

wordlist as a filename `f`, **45 bytes**

```perl6
->$w,\f{grep({/:i"$w"/},f.IO.words)/$w.chars}
```

wordlist as a list `l`, **36 bytes**

```perl6
->$w,\l{grep({/:i"$w"/},l)/$w.chars}
```

using placeholder variables, and reverse (`R`) meta-operator, **33 bytes**

```perl6
{$^w.chars R/grep {/:i"$w"/},$^z}
```

using `.comb` to get a list of characters, rather than `.chars` to get a count, **32 bytes**

```perl6
{$^w.comb R/grep {/:i"$w"/},$^z}
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
{             # block lambda with placeholder parameters ｢$w｣ ｢$z｣

  $^w         # declare first parameter ( word to search for )
  .comb       # list of characters ( turns into count in numeric context )

  R[/]        # division operator with parameters reversed

  grep        # list the values that match ( turns into count in numeric context )

    {         # lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
      /       # match against ｢$_｣
        :i    # ignorecase
        "$w"  # the word as a simple string
      /
    },

    $^z       # declare the wordlist to search through
              #( using a later letter in the alphabet
              #  so it is the second argument )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### awk: 31 bytes

Passing the word as the `w` variable to the `awk` command, and the file in `<stdin>`:

```
$0~w{N++}END{print N/length(w)}
```

Sample output:

```
 $ awk -vw=hello '$0~w{N++}END{print N/length(w)}' /usr/share/dict/words
 2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 54 bytes

Assumes the word list in `$w`.

```
<?=count(preg_grep("/$argv[1]/",$w))/strlen($argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 53 bytes

Not that exciting :/

```
#(/(count(filter(fn[w](.contains w %))W))(count %)1.)
```

That `1.` is there to convert a rational into a float. I pre-loaded words into `W` as such:

```
(def W (map clojure.string/lower-case (clojure.string/split (slurp "/usr/share/dict/words") #"\n")))
```